# Pygame: Order of appending to a list is messing up

Tags: python-3.7

I have made a loop to add a picture, an x coordinate and a y coordinate to a list in that specific order. However, I get an error further into my program and have figured out that the problem is the order that these elements are added to the list. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

---

Code:

```
zero = pygame.image.load("0.png").convert_alpha()

one = pygame.image.load("1.png").convert_alpha()

two = pygame.image.load("2.png").convert_alpha()

three = pygame.image.load("3.png").convert_alpha()

four = pygame.image.load("4.png").convert_alpha()

five = pygame.image.load("5.png").convert_alpha()

six = pygame.image.load("6.png").convert_alpha()

seven = pygame.image.load("7.png").convert_alpha()

eight = pygame.image.load("8.png").convert_alpha()

nine = pygame.image.load("9.png").convert_alpha()

numList = [zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]

blitList = []

i=0

while i<10:

    i=i+1

    numX = random.randint(20,1320)

    numY = random.randint(20,700)

    number = random.choice(numList)

    blitList.append(number)

    blitList.append(numX)

    blitList.append(numY)
```

---

When the list was printed:

```
[<Surface(70x69x32 SW)>, 506, 110, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 1177, 559, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 524, 467, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 263, 232, 630, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 551, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 58, 123, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 1157, 520, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 772, 640, <Surface(69x69x32 SW)>, 178, 522]
```

The order should be '[surface], x-value, y-value...' and so on but when I printed it, the one that had a messed up order changed each time. (in this case it was the fifth)

Comment: I noticed you've received a few downvotes for this question. You might have more luck if you update the title of this question to more specifically articulate the issue you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im fairly new to this but maybe you pick the same Picture two times during the loop or somthing and thats Whats messing it up. If you shuffle numlist outside the loop and append from the suffled numlist will help. The loop is Also 1 short from picking all objects.

-Terje-

Code:

```
zero = pygame.image.load("0.png").convert_alpha()

one = pygame.image.load("1.png").convert_alpha()

two = pygame.image.load("2.png").convert_alpha()

three = pygame.image.load("3.png").convert_alpha()

four = pygame.image.load("4.png").convert_alpha()

five = pygame.image.load("5.png").convert_alpha()

six = pygame.image.load("6.png").convert_alpha()

seven = pygame.image.load("7.png").convert_alpha()

eight = pygame.image.load("8.png").convert_alpha()

nine = pygame.image.load("9.png").convert_alpha()

numList = [zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]

Random.shuffle(numList)

blitList = []

i=0

while i<10:

    numX = random.randint(20,1320)

    numY = random.randint(20,700)

    number = numList[i]

    blitList.append(number)

    blitList.append(numX)

    blitList.append(numY)

    i=i+1
```